# Laravel validation messages array indices starting from 0

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

If in a form request I have rules

```
[
    'items' => ['required', 'array'],
    'items.*' => ['required', 'numeric'],
]
```

Then error message returns like this:

```
"items.0" => array:1 [
  0 => "The selected items.0 is invalid."
]
```

Is there any way to have the message look like "The selected items #1 is invalid" or something similar, that is actually human readable?

Please note, I need this for the whole system globally, there's already >500 form request classes, although not that many are using array validation, so changing extended class or adding a trait wouldn't be too horrible

Comment: can you show your data set of request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom Request then You can do like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        foreach ($this->request->get('items') as $key => $value) {
            $rules[$key] = 'required';
        }
        return $rules;
    }
```

Hope This Help you

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
[
   'items' => ['required', 'array'],
   'items.*' => ['required', 'numeric'],
],
[
    'items.required' => 'Your Message',
]
```

Comment: I could do `items.*.numeric => '...'`, but that's a solution only for one request and still doesn't allow me to have `'Item #1 ...'` instead of `'items.0 ...'`.